# Configuring centrifugo with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to configure Centrifugo with Docker, however, it fails to be available on localhost:8427. What could the cause of the issue? When I start the container and run curl command "curl localhost:8427", the page is not found. I would appreciate any advice.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
  centrifugo:
    image: centrifugo/centrifugo:v4.0.4
    container_name: tradegame_backend_local_centrifugo
    command: centrifugo -c /centrifugo/config.json
    expose: 
      - 8427
    ports:
      - "8427:8427"
    volumes:
      - "./centrifugo.json:/centrifugo/config.json"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65536
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
```

Logs from the container:

```
local_centrifugo  | {"level":"info","version":"4.0.4","runtime":"go1.19.3","pid":1,"engine":"redis","gomaxprocs":8,"time":"2023-12-18T17:43:30Z","message":"starting Centrifugo"}
local_centrifugo  | {"level":"info","path":"/centrifugo/config.json","time":"2023-12-18T17:43:30Z","message":"using config file"}
local_centrifugo  | {"level":"info","algorithms":"HS256, HS384, HS512","time":"2023-12-18T17:43:30Z","message":"enabled JWT verifiers"}
local_centrifugo  | {"level":"info","time":"2023-12-18T17:43:30Z","message":"Redis: redis:6379/1, using password: false"}
local_centrifugo  | {"level":"warn","time":"2023-12-18T17:43:30Z","message":"DEBUG mode enabled, see /debug/pprof"}
local_centrifugo  | {"level":"warn","time":"2023-12-18T17:43:30Z","message":"usage of allowed_origins * is discouraged for security reasons, consider setting exact list of origins"}
local_centrifugo  | {"level":"info","time":"2023-12-18T17:43:30Z","message":"serving websocket, API, debug endpoints on :8427"}
```

Centrifugo config.json

```
{
    "v3_use_offset": true,
    "token_hmac_secret_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "admin_password": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "admin_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "api_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "port": "8427",
    "debug": true,
    "allow_subscribe_for_client": true,
    "allow_subscribe_for_anonymous": true,
    "user_subscribe_to_personal": true,
    "user_personal_single_connection": false,
    "user_personal_channel_namespace": "personal",
    "namespaces": [
      {
        "name": "personal",
        "presence": true
      }
    ],
    "engine": "redis",
    "redis_address": "redis://redis:6379/1",
    "user_status": {
      "enabled": true,
      "use_redis_from_engine": true
    },
    "allowed_origins": [
      "*"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was with the URL. Containers can communicate internally using namespaces and not localhost. I changed the Django config and it worked.

```
CENTRIFUGO_HOST=http://centrifugo
```